# A lot of global vars in config file especialle db related, shall I make a db-layer?

Tags: php, database, pdo, global-variables

I'm having a config.php file with some global variables in it:
basically most of them are related to connect to my DB.

An example:

```
$WEBDBHOST = 'localhost';
$WEBDBPORT = '3306';
$WEBDBNAME = 'db';
$WEBDBUSERNAME = 'root';
$WEBDBPASSWORD = '' ;
```

And most of the time it's used like:

```
$dbw = new PDO("mysql:host=$WEBDBHOST;port=$WEBDBPORT;dbname=$WEBDBNAME", $WEBDBUSERNAME, $WEBDBPASSWORD);
```

This doesn't look efficient to me at all!
How can improve my code? Shall I make some kind of database layer that includes the global vars and make some kind of getWEBDB() that returns a new pdo object?

Or is there some better way of dealing with this? Keep in mind that I'm having more than one DB, so I was thinking about getWebDB(), getGameDB() etc.

Comment: That's how I've seen it done in lots of systems, so I personally don't see a problem with it. You can put it into a method or class if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should create a db layer. Everyone should.

No, not because of "alot of global vars in config file". As a matter of fact, there should be only *one* global variable

```
$cfg['db']['game']['host']    = 'localhost';
$cfg['db']['game']['port']    = '3306';
$cfg['db']['game']['base']    = 'db';
$cfg['db']['game']['user']    = 'root';
$cfg['db']['game']['pass']    = '';
$cfg['db']['game']['charset'] = 'utf8';
```

Now you can pass desired configuration option to a class like this

```
$gamedb = new DBLayer($cfg['game']);
```

and have constructor like this

```
function __construct($db)
{
    $dsn  = "mysql:";
    $dsn .= "host=".   $db['host'].";";
    $dsn .= "dbname=". $db['name'].";";
    $dsn .= "port=".   $db['port'].";";
    $dsn .= "charset=".$db['charset'];

    $opt = array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    );
    return new PDO($dsn,$db['user'],$db['pass'], $opt);
}
```

Comment: Do you suggest using the global keyword for $cfg (like: global $cfg) or use $GLOBALS['cfg']['db']['game']['host'], though that seems to become quite lengthy, but then I dont have to use the global keyword in every php file where I want to use it. Or is there a better way.

Thanks btw for the good explanation above :)

Comment: use whatever you wish - these two ways are the same. You could use some fancy way too - google for Dependency Injection for example.